# R: adding vertical line to barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

```
mydat <- c(rep(4:10, each = 3), rep(1:2, each = 2))
barplot(table(mydat))
abline(v = 3, col = "blue")
```

This gives me the following plot: [image]
I want a vertical line at `x=3`. However, because of the way the x-axis is spaced out, the vertical line doesn't appear to be in the right place. How can I fix this? i.e. I want my plot to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Just curious: Why don't you show an empty space for `3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To plot a line between the 2nd and the 3rd bars, assign the return value of `barplot` and then plot in the `mean` value of the 2nd and 3rd of those values.

```
bp <- as.vector(barplot(table(mydat)))
abline(v = mean(bp[2:3]), col = "blue")
```

[image]